# Templates and Initializing class members

Tags: c++, templates, initialization

I'm struggling to understand why the definition of CC below generates the error following error message  (Visual Studio 2019). Could someone please explain.

"Error (active) E0415   no suitable constructor exists to convert from "int" to "C" .."

Thanks

```
struct A
{
    int i ;
};

template< typename T >
struct B
{
    T i ;
};

struct C 
    : public B<int>
{   
};

const A AA = { 1 }; // OK
const C CC = { 1 }; // ERROR
```

Comment: [Compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/xdovY3) with v19.24 and `/std:c++17`.

Comment: I don't know c++17, I'm a bit of an old timer.  But the error message is telling you that you need to add a constructor (or, apparently, move to a later C++ version).  The variable you want to initialize is in the base class function, so you need a way to pass it down to the base class initializor.

Comment: @Basya: `C` is an aggregate as of C++17; brace elision should apply.

Comment: You are using [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization). `C` is not an aggregate in C++14 and earlier, and is an aggregate in C++17 and later. So `const C CC = { 1 };` is valid in C++17, but not valid in C++14.

Comment: Thanks. Changed VS2019 from 'default' to C++17 and the error has gone. Thanks.

Comment: @DavisHerring  I understand that it works in C++17, but that is apparently not his environment.  Thanks for the explanation of why it works in C++17 though.